# How do I get predict in SparkALS Implicit to use multiple cores?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using the Spark ALS Implicit recommender code. Training the model works fine using multiple cores/parallelism:

```
model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, lambda_, blocks=-1, alpha=alpha)
```

I have also configured the Spark context parameters to use multiple cores and I can see that the model training part is using multiple cores.

But when I use predict functions such as:

```
Item = model.recommendUsers(item_id, 1000000)
```

this is quite slow (takes ~70secs for 1 million users)

I can't find any documentation on how to make the predict and recommend functions use multiple cores, or how to multi-thread this. Is this possible?